# preg_split to seperate input

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a website using PHP.

I am using a `preg_split()` to separate a given string which looks like `+word1 -word2 -"word word"`.
But I need them in the following form `+word1`, `-word2`, `-"word word"`.

Currently, I have this one:

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s\"]*\"([^\"]+)\"[\s\"]*|" . "[\s\"]*'([^']+)'[\s\"]*|" . "[\s\"]+/", $search_expression, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but it didn't work as I wish: I need to do it in this way to get it work:
`+word1 -word2 '-"word word"'`.

Does someone have a better regex or idea?

Comment: Your expected output does not agree with the input.  Please fix your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to match from a double quote till a double quote and don't split on that match using [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). Then match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars to split on.

```
"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CnjfRV/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/RFU89)

For example

```
$search_expression = '+word1 -word2 -"word word"';
$words = preg_split("~\"[^\"]+\"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+~", $search_expression);
print_r($words);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => +word1
    [1] => -word2
    [2] => -"word word"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler expression with greedy `?` works for matching your examples:

```
preg_match_all('/[+-][^+-]+ ?/', $search_expression, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => +word1 
    [1] => -word2 
    [2] => -"word word"
)
```

Se [Example](https://regex101.com/r/y06UVi/1).